# "Obect has no method" when calling other function from within callback function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using backbone and I'm trying to set a callback as below:

```
app.myView = Backbone.View.extend({

     events : {
        'click #myButton' : 'onClick',
        },

    onClick : function(e) {
        var self = this;
        myModel.save(null, {
            success : self.successAction
        });
        return false;
    },

    successAction : function() {
        this.myOtherFunction();
    },

    myOtherFunction : function() {
        this.$el.hide();
    }

});
```

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'myOtherFunction'
```

How can I call another function of the same class from within a callback function?

Also, I would like to ask, is it in general possible to pass parameters with the callback function?
Like this:

```
myModel.save({
    "success" : successAction(param1, param2)
});

successAction : function(param1, param2) {
    this.myOtherFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that when the function `successAction` is invoked it is invoked from the global scope, so the context points to global object inside the callback, you can use [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (with shim support for older browsers), try :

```
onClick : function(e) {
    var self = this;
    myModel.save({
        "success" : self.successAction.bind(self)
    });
    return false;
},
```

and to pass arguments you could use:

```
myModel.save({
    "success" :  self.successAction.bind(self, param1, param2)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! What is shim support, do I need to add a library for older browsers?

Comment: Why bother with `self` when you're not using it?

Comment: @muistooshort I am not sure where op is using it.... This might be a simplification of original code he has.

Comment: @ChristopherMasser: There's always [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) if you're not sure if all your browsers will have `Function.bind`.

Comment: @ChristopherMasser shim means pollyfill. if you look at the link in my answer scroll down and read pollyfill. this is native js for bind. Similarly you have $.proxy in jquery, _.bind (as in the previous comment) in unerscore etc...